# Kivy sdl2 & glew Not Installing Properly

Tags: python, kivy

First off, I'm very new to `Python`, `Kivy`, and even Stack Exchange for that matter, so hopefully there is something small I'm looking over.

I've been trying to install Kivy and keep getting the error:

> Unable to get Window, abort.

The full error message can be seen [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5677). I recognize that sdl2 library (or package?) is not installed properly.

What is confusing me is that when I run the following.

```
python -m pip install kivy.deps.sdl2
```

I receive a successful install message. However, if I try to uninstall it, using the same command with uninstall in place of install, it says:

> WARNING: Skipping kivy.deps.sdl2 as it is not installed.

I get the same results with the `glew` dependency. I have also tried installing these packages with the command:

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypi win32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
```

Is there a reason it thinks they are being installed and then not being able to find them to uninstall? I tried disabling Windows Smart Screen in case it was blocking an unsigned .dll file.

Am I making a mistake somewhere? I hope I'm not opening up duplicate threads. Thanks in advance for any insight. I am also using Atom instead of PyCharm, if that makes a difference, my OS is Win10 Pr0 64 bit.

Comment: what version of python are you using? you can check by using `python --version`

Comment: CMD reads 3.7.8rc1

Comment: what's the output when you run this command: `python -m pip show kivy kivy.deps.sdl2`?

Comment: `Name: Kivy

Version: 1.11.1

Summary: A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated multitouch applications.

Home-page: http://kivy.org

Author: Kivy Team and other contributors

Author-email: kivy-dev@googlegroups.com

License: MIT

Home-page: http://kivy.org/

Author: Kivy Crew

Author-email: kivy-dev@googlegroups.com

License: zlib
Location: c:\users\nathan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packag
es

Requires:
Required-by:`

Comment: Imgur Link to screenshot of readout:
https://imgur.com/z0NRQnU